# Implementing digital signature on Weblogic ServiceControl Client

Tags: web-services, security, x509, wss4j

Our application is a consumer of a web service that has asked us to implement digital signature (X.509 based) in our request SOAP header. We need to have in the header tags like `<ds:SignedInfo>, <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>, <ds:CanonicalizationMethod>`. It's actually a lot similar to the xml [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/604108/Web-Services/java/java-code-generate-SOAP-headers).

Now, as a client we are not using clientgen. Nor is the server side willing to make this into a WS-Policy. I searched a lot in the Oracle documentation but it seems to end at the assumption that the server side needs to have this policy enforced to the web service. That can't happen. We can't use client side policy too because the examples I came across at Oracle's website seem to suggest that it only works for client code generated via clientgen while our code uses the ServiceControl.

Just today I came across WSS4J but I am not sure if that is the answer to what I am searching for. It certainly seems plausible but will it work in my scenario (considering that we have Weblogic ServiceController) while all examples for WSS4J seem to use Axis.

I have spent last few days searching on this and I am getting to the point of frustration. Please help!

Thanks,
Ak

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and finally we are using the Apache CXF library for creating the client and written some interceptors for it. In our case the web service is having authentication header and it is X509 enabled. The below code works for me, I am sharing this with you:-

For generating Web Service Client offline, you can save the xml of the wsdl in your localmachine and then use wsconsume/wsdl2java command for creating the stub.

In the below code you can skip addSoapHeader part if there is no userName and pwd set for the web service
in SOAP Header.

TestClient.java:-

```
            import java.math.BigDecimal;
            import java.math.BigInteger;
            import java.net.Authenticator;
            import java.net.MalformedURLException;
            import java.net.URL;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.Date;
            import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
            import java.util.HashMap;
            import java.util.Iterator;
            import java.util.List;
            import java.util.Map;
            import java.util.Properties;
            import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
            import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
            import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
            import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
            import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
            import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
            import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
            import javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature;
            import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapHeader;
            import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
            import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
            import org.apache.cxf.headers.Header;
            import org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding;
            import org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.AddressingProperties;
            import org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.AttributedURIType;
            import org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.EndpointReferenceType;
            import org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.VersionTransformer;
            import org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.AddressingPropertiesImpl;
            import org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor;
            import org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandlerConstants;
            import com.icbase.tsamplex509.ArrayOfDetailLineItem;
            import com.icbase.tsamplex509.ArrayOfInventoryLineItem;
            import com.icbase.tsamplex509.AuthHeader;
            import com.icbase.tsamplex509.CompleteInventory;
            import com.icbase.tsamplex509.DetailLineItem;
            import com.icbase.tsamplex509.InventoryLineItem;
            import com.icbase.tsamplex509.OrderAdd;
            import com.icbase.tsamplex509.OrderStatus;
            import com.icbase.tsamplex509.ResultMessage;
            import com.icbase.tsamplex509.Service;
            import com.icbase.tsamplex509.ServiceSoap;
            import com.st.passport.PassportWebServiceHandler;
            import com.st.passport.UserInfo;
            import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl;

            public class TestClient 
            {
             private static String proxyUser = "javaMagician";
             private static String proxyPassword = "myProxyPws";
             private static String proxyHost = "sxf4.dlh.ts.com";
             private static String proxyPort = "8080";
             private static String wsURL = "http://www.wsdoamin.com/tssamplex509/service.asmx?WSDL";


             public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, Exception 
             {
              Authenticator.setDefault(new ANSAuthenticationHandler(proxyUser,proxyPassword));
              System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
              System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);

              Service service = new Service(new URL(wsURL),new QName("http://www.wsdoamin.com/tssamplex509/", "Service"));

              ServiceSoap port = service.getServiceSoap(new AddressingFeature(true,true));

              Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port); 

              enableWSAddressing(client);

              enableWsSecurity(client);

              addSOAPHeader(client);

              System.out.println("Invoking Web Service ...");

              //Calling First Web service
              CompleteInventory getProductResponse = port.getproduct("*");


              System.out.println("Result :: " + getProductResponse.getResultMessage().getResult().name());
              System.out.println("Return Message :: " + getProductResponse.getResultMessage().getMessage());
              System.out.println("------------------- Inventory -------------------");



             }

             private static void enableWSAddressing(Client client) {
              AddressingProperties maps = new AddressingPropertiesImpl();
              EndpointReferenceType ref = new EndpointReferenceType();
              AttributedURIType add = new AttributedURIType();
              add.setValue("http://www.wsdoamin.com/tssamplex509/getproduct");
              ref.setAddress(add);
              maps.setReplyTo(ref);
              maps.setFaultTo(ref);
              maps.exposeAs(VersionTransformer.Names200408.WSA_NAMESPACE_NAME);
              client.getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.addressing.context", maps); 
             }

             private static void enableWsSecurity(Client client) {
              Properties properties = new Properties();
              properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider","org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
              properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type","jks");
              properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password","changeit");
              properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias","ts_p&s_ws");
              properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file", "cert/TS_P&S_WS.jks");
              Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
              outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION,  WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE);
              outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "ts_p&s_ws");
              outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS,ANSAuthenticationHandler.class.getName()); 
              outProps.put("cryptoProperties", properties);
              outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_REF_ID,"cryptoProperties");
              outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");
              client.getEndpoint().getOutInterceptors().add(new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps)); 
              client.getEndpoint().getOutInterceptors().add(new org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor());
              client.getEndpoint().getInInterceptors().add(new org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor());
             }

             private static void addSOAPHeader(Client client) throws JAXBException {
              List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
              AuthHeader authHeader = new AuthHeader();
              authHeader.setUsername("ts");
              authHeader.setPassword("46u43242bw3670");
              SoapHeader tokenHeader = new SoapHeader(new QName("http://www.wsdoamin.com/tssamplex509", "AuthHeader"), authHeader,new JAXBDataBinding(AuthHeader.class));
              headers.add(tokenHeader);
              client.getRequestContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);
             }

            }
```

ANSAuthenticationHandler.java

```
            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.net.Authenticator;
            import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
            import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
            import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
            import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;
            import org.apache.ws.security.WSPasswordCallback;

            public class ANSAuthenticationHandler extends Authenticator implements CallbackHandler {

             private String proxyUser;
             private String proxyPassword;

             public ANSAuthenticationHandler() {
              super();
             }
             public ANSAuthenticationHandler(String proxyUser, String proxyPassword) {
              super();
              this.proxyUser = proxyUser;
              this.proxyPassword = proxyPassword;
             }

                public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException 
                {
                WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];
                System.err.println("CallbackHandler providing password for :: "+pc.getIdentifier());

                if ("ts_p&s_ws".equals(pc.getIdentifier())) {
                 pc.setPassword("changeit");
                }
                }

              public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
             {
              System.err.println("Feeding username and password for ["+getRequestingPrompt()+"] to ["+getRequestingHost()+":"+getRequestingPort()+"] for ["+getRequestingScheme()+"] scheme");
              return (new PasswordAuthentication(proxyUser, proxyPassword.toCharArray()));
             }
            }
```